# False Truths in PHP SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, apache

I'm having difficulty reasoning with this output.

The problem is with one server, not the other and Somehow the values are being calculated as multiple "truths" when there is only one value that is the same.

Is this a PHP version auto-interpretation thing, where PHP is trying to play with a number rather than a string?

Any ideas will help. Thanks!

```
$SelectedID="20140115214529625";

$con=GetSQLConnection("SomeDataBaseSomewhere");

$sqlQ="SELECT * FROM StoryTable ORDER BY  Name ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlQ);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($SelectedID==$row['newPermID']){
        echo "Data: ".$SelectedID.", ".$row['newPermID']."\n";
    }else{}
}
mysqli_close($con);


Output:
Data: 20140115214529625, 20140115214529623
Data: 20140115214529625, 20140115214529624
Data: 20140115214529625, 20140115214529625 < Should Be The Only True Value???
Data: 20140115214529625, 20140115214529626
```

`

Comment: More likely to be a difference between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PHP given the size of these values if $row['newPermID'] is an integer

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? I think some bugs relating to these kinds of comparison were fixed at some point.

Comment: Debug, `var_dump($SelectedID)` and `var_dump($row['newPermID']` and compare

Comment: 5.5.10 (correct) to 5.2.9 . So it's trying to do a number?

How would I tell version 5.2.9 to treat these as a string value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a php that is too cool and does some unexpected magic under the hood.

As soon as it spots the 2 strings look like numbers - it converts them to numbers and compares after (and you presumably run 32 bit php which just overflows such a big integers).

Example:

```
var_dump('01' == '1'); // true
```

To avoid it use `===` comparison which will prevent it from doing that.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I just tested it, and you're right. +1 for your solution.

Comment: That's it.. Never seen a override like that.. Thanks Zerkms!

Comment: It's not an override `===` compares by type.

Comment: @Ian Brindley: I didn't say anything about "override". If you addressed it to someone else - please put `@name` so that they received a notification, not me.